# Definition of 'access function' in relation to the activation record

Tags: compiler-construction, heap-memory, stack-memory

What does the term 'access function' refer to in compiler design? Specifically, the access functions present in runtime.

For example, you could construct an access function for a 3D column-major array like so: "The subscript ranges of the three dimensions can be named min(1), min(2), min(3), max(1), max(2), and max(3), where min(1), min(2), and min(3) are lower bounds for dimension one, dimension two, and dimension three respectively, and max(1), max(2), and max(3) are upper bounds for dimension one, two, and three respectively. Assume an element size."

What would an access function refer to in the above context? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: A function that allows you to access the data?

Comment: I assume a function that does the indexing, that computes the address of an element. But that does not exist at runtime in compiled executables.

Comment: What did your teacher/professor say during the lectures? What does your text-book say?

Comment: This seems very specific to whatever source you're learning from, and to the particular compiler you are expected to implement at this point.

Comment: Textbook doesn't always use this term specifically as our teacher's lecture notes, which is why I am confused. Our lectures stated it was a function allowing access to data in memory, just as Alan Birtles's comment says. However, I am still confused between this concept and the actual access() function present in some languages

Comment: If you're thinking of [the POSIX `access` function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/access.html) it does something completely different.

Comment: Alright, thank you for clarifying! I believe this has answered my question